# Fazer consulta com distinct no Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Tenho a seguinte tabela:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Preciso contar a quantidade de registros onde o `supplier_id` seja igual a 2 mas sem repetir a coluna `order_id`. Nesse caso iria retornar 1, já que tem dois registros com 2 na `supplier_id`, mas `order_id` é 1 nos dois registros

Usei a consulta abaixo no mysql e retornou corretamente 1 registro:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT order_id) FROM timelines WHERE supplier_id = 2;
```

Utilizei a consulta abaixo no Laravel e me retornou 2 registros

```
DB::table('timelines')
    ->where('supplier_id', 2)
    ->groupBy('order_id')
    ->count();
```

Como poderia fazer para retornar a quantidade correta que no caso é 1 registro?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Utilize o `selectRaw` na `queryBuilder`

```
$db = \DB::table('timelines')
       ->selectRaw('COUNT(DISTINCT order_id) AS total')
       ->where('supplier_id', 2)
       ->first();

var_dump($db->total);
```

> Porém tenha cuidado ao utilizar, isso é vulnerável a ataques SQL Injection.

Da maneira que você fez, quando você debuga o código, você recebe a query

```
select count(*) as aggregate from `timelines` where `supplier_id` = 2 group by `order_id`;
```

Apesar o `GROUP BY` retornar apenas um elemento, o `count(*)` irá contar todos os registros, independente do `GROUP BY`.

Caso não queira utilizar o `selectRaw`, você pode utilizar dessa forma:

```
$db = \DB::table('timelines')
    ->select('order_id')
    ->where('supplier_id', 2)
    ->groupBy('order_id')
    ->get(); 

var_dump( count($db) );
```

Comment: O groupBy não era para funcionar? Tem como sem o selectRaw?

Comment: Editei minha resposta, adicione as respostas para essas outras dúvidas.

Comment: As duas formas que passou funcionaram. A segunda forma gera um erro: sql_mode=only_full_group_by. Coloquei false em config/database.php e o erro sumiu. Colocar strict como false tem algum problema?Teria como fazer da segunda forma sem desabilitar esse strict mode?

Comment: É possível sim, esse erro é porque você está utilizando um campo no `group by`, mas não está selecionando esse mesmo campo no `select`. Para corrigir isso basta adicionar `->select('order_id')` na Query Builder.